# Register form similar to facebook once CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a register component which contain the red wrapper and blue form. It opens when you press the button in the navigation.

The problem is that I want to scroll just over the red component when the register form is opend, not over the whole site. So when the screen is big enough, you'll see the whole register form, but when you have to small screen you will be able to scroll it. It should looks like the register form on facebook when you click 'create new account'.

The red Wrapper component covers only part of the page so as to fit the register form inside. Black border on the photo means the screen.

[image]

My register component code looks like this, but I don't know how to make scrolling just over the "red" component. The "blue" register form should stay in place when is scrolling. How can I do this correctly?

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
`;

const Form = styled.form`
  background-color: white;
  padding: 50px 80px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;

const StyledInput = styled.input`
  padding: 10px 12px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid ${({ error }) => (error ? "red" : "#d6d6d6")};
  outline: none;
  width: 250px;

  :focus {
    border: 1px solid #00b4ff;
    color: #00b4ff;
  }
`;

const LoginButton = styled.button`
  background-color: ${({ facebook }) => (facebook ? "#4c69ba" : "#191919")};
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0;
  display: block;

  :hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }

  :last-child {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
`;

const Logo = styled.img`
  width: 150px;
  height: 22px;
`;

const LogoHolder = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const FieldType = styled.div`
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 15px;
`;

const CLose = styled(IoMdClose)`
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  color: #191919;

  :hover {
    color: #00b4ff;
  }
`;

const StyledCheckbox = styled(Checkbox)`
  margin: 15px 0;
`;

const Error = styled.div`
  font-size: 11px;
  color: red;
  margin-top: ${({ statute }) => (statute ? "-10px" : "3px")};
  margin-bottom: ${({ statute }) => (statute ? "15px" : "0")};
  width: 250px;
`;

const Register = ({ setRegisterView }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
        <Form>
          <CLose onClick={() => setRegisterView(false)} />
          <LogoHolder>
            <Logo src={logo} />
          </LogoHolder>
          <FieldType>First Name</FieldType>
          <StyledInput
            name="first_name"
            type="text"
          />
          <FieldType>Last Name</FieldType>
          <StyledInput
            name="last_name"
            type="text"
          />
          <FieldType>City</FieldType>
          <StyledInput
            name="city"
            type="text"
          />
          <FieldType>Email</FieldType>
          <StyledInput
            name="email"
            type="email"
          />
          <FieldType>Password</FieldType>
          <StyledInput
            name="password"
            type="password"
          />
          <FieldType>Repeat password</FieldType>
          <StyledInput
            name="repeated_password"
            type="password"
          />
          <StyledCheckbox
            text="Accept statute."
          />
          <LoginButton type="submit">SIGN UP</LoginButton>
          <LoginButton facebook>LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK</LoginButton>
        </Form>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Comment: I mean the rest of site should be still there but the user should scroll just over the red component when it's opened

Comment: and the blue component should has a constant height

Answer (score 1):

I got it! I've added `overflow-y: auto`, `min` and `max height` to the Wrapper component and `overflow: hidden` to the `body` when the register form is opened.

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
`;
```

To the Form component I've added `height:100%`.